# How to create mulitple series in excel using apple script

Tags: excel, applescript

I want to create a chart with multiple series in excel 2011 using apple script.

```
    tell application "Microsoft Excel"
    tell worksheet "Sheet1" of active workbook
        set obj to make new chart object at end with properties {left position:20, top:88, width:33, height:90}
        set ochart to chart of obj
        set chart type of ochart to column clustered
        set series 1 of series collection to ochart
        tell series 1
            set xvalues to "=Sheet1!$B$7:$B$10"
            set name to "shartseries1"
        end tell
    end tell
end tell
```

In this script chart is created and chart type is set successfully, but chart series is not created.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
tell application "Microsoft Excel"
    tell worksheet "Sheet1" of active workbook
        set obj to make new chart object at end with properties {left position:20, top:88, width:33, height:90}
        set ochart to chart of obj
        tell ochart
            set chart type to column clustered
            set newSeries to make new series at end with properties {series values:"=Sheet1!$B$7:$B$10", xvalues:"=Sheet1!$B$7:$B$10", name:"shartseries1"}
        end tell
    end tell
end tell
```

Comment: Hi, If series values is "={1}" then script is through error i.e "Microsoft Excel got an error:Can't make class series".   set new series to make new series at end with properties {series value:"={1}"}                   please replay